# Backtracking line search algorithm - Why have non-zero alpha?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

Line search methods for convex optimization are of two main types

1. Exact line search - explicit minimization $\min_\eta f(x+\eta \,\Delta x) $
2. Inexact line search (Backtracking example) - Pick $\alpha \in (0,0.5), \beta \in (0,1), t=1$

while $f(x +t\,\Delta x) > f(x) + t \alpha x^T \, \nabla f(x) $:

$$t=\beta\cdot t$$

My question : Why is backtracking line search advantageous over a crude inexact minimization like the one below:

Set $\beta=.9, t=1$, check $f(x +t\,\Delta x)$,

If $f(x +t\,\Delta x) < f(x) $, terminate,
else $t=\beta\cdot t$

Why have an alpha parameter and complicate the termination condition like in the case of backtracking line search, the only thing it seems to guarantee is function decrease i.e $f(x+1)<f(x)$, but this can be done by the above simple crude procedure as well - discrete evaluations of $f(x +t\,\Delta x)$.

Comment: What is $\beta$ doing here?  I don't see that you are using it anywhere.

Comment: If f(x+tΔx)<f(x), terminate, else  β=β⋅t. I am merely decrementing the step size in a discrete scaled fashion until we are sure the new function value is lesser. Just want to know why this simple approach is not better than the more complex backtracking line search.

Comment: sorry, I have corrected it.

Comment: the error occurs twice; also why do you have $\beta=1$? Your method generates a decreasing sequence, but can't it converge to a suboptimal solution?

Comment: I have not done any sort of convergence analysis.  $\beta$ is anywhere from 0 to 1. My question was that this ensures $f(x_{t+1})<f(x_t)$ similar to backtracking line search and seems much simpler, so why is this is not  used in practice?

Comment: This is a good question, the answer is a little non-obvious. The classic example of a problem that can occur with your simplification is shown on slide 5 here: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hauser/hauser_lecture2.pdf

Comment: You may make the slides 5-10 as an answer so I may accept it, particularly the slide about choosing alpha greater than the magnitude of gradient warrants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ f(x_{k+1})<f(x_k) $ need not imply that the sequence $x_k$ converges, making such simplistic methods proposed above insufficient.

An example of such a non-convergent sequence is as below. [image] $f_k$ is decreasing, but the sequence of $x$ does not converge. 
This is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tqaXIM6kEE&t=2702s